# What will be the way to calculate number of sequences formed using 1, 2, 3 for some specific length

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to calculate the number of sequences where each sequence will include at least one occurrence of 1, 2 and 3 for a given length, Suppose for

```
length 1 --> number of sequences is 0,
length 2 --> number of sequences is 0,
length 3 --> number of sequences is 6
```

I am not able to calculate it further suppose for length 4, 5, n.
What will be the way to calculate it?

Comment: This would appear to be a duplicate of this [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009409/).